# Add a number in a huge ASCII file

Tags: awk, perl, floating-point, numeric-data

**Background:**

(1) Here is a screen capture of a part of my ascii file (over 600Mb):

[image]

(1.1) Here is a part of the code:

```
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.043678e-05, 3.661498e-05, 2.070347e-05, 
    2.47175e-05, 1.49877e-05, 3.031176e-05, 2.12128e-05, 2.817522e-05, 
    1.802658e-05, 7.192285e-06, 8.467806e-06, 2.047874e-05, 9.621194e-05, 
    4.467542e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000421869, 
    0.0003081213, 0.0001938675, 8.70334e-05, 0.0002973858, 0.0003385935, 
    8.763598e-05, 2.743326e-05, 0, 0.0001043894, 3.409237e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.503832e-05, 1.433673e-05, 2.557402e-05, 
    3.081098e-05, 4.044465e-05, 2.480817e-05, 2.681778e-05, 1.533265e-05, 
    2.3156e-05, 3.193812e-05, 5.325314e-05, 1.639066e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.259782e-05, 0.0004197799, 2.65868e-05, 0.0002485498, 
    3.485129e-05, 2.454055e-05, 0.0002096856, 0.0001910835, 1.969936e-05, 
    2.974743e-05, 8.983165e-05, 0.0004263787, 0.0004444561, 0.000241368, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

(2) Each red rectangle contains 74 elements.

(3) I want to add a number, e.g. 0.001, to each of the non-zero entries.

---

**My thought:**

(1) I was told by my friend that `/perl` can help to finish this task but I am new to this programming script.

(2) I guess the strategy is to read each of the numbers and

```
(i) if it is a zero, then neglect it; or,
(ii) if it is non-zero, then add 0.001 to this number and replace this number.
```

(3) My worry is that:

If `/perl` is able to read a number in scientific notation (i.e. 1.303637e-05 is indeed equal to 0.00001303637)?

Comment: Please give us an example input file, instead of image. We can't copy and paste with image.

Comment: @cuonglm Thanks for your comment, and the question is edited.

Comment: So only every other rectangle then?

Comment: @mikeserv The ASCII file contains many blocks like those two red rectangles.

Comment: Right, but, in your picture you highlight two rectangles - and there is one between them. Do you want only the conversions/additions performed on every *other* record or *every* record?

Comment: @mikeserv sorry for my confusion. Indeed, I would like to perform addition on every block, not only those highlighted.

I just highlighted randomly two rectangles in order to describe the number of elements in each block. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
perl -pe 's/([0-9.e-]+)/$1 == 0 ? $1 : .001 + $1/ge' < input.txt > output.txt
```

- `-p` process the file line by line
- `s/patern/replacement/` is a substitution.
- `[0-9.e-]+` matches one or more of the given characters, i.e. the numbers
- `()` remembers each number in `$1`
- `/g` applies the substitution globally, i.e. as many times as needed for each line
- `/e` evaluates the replacement as code
- `condition ? then : else` is the "ternary operator": if the condition is true (`$1 == 0`, i.e. the remembered number equals 0), it returns the number, otherwise it adds .001 to it.

Comment: Thanks, it works even I add a extremely small value, says, 0.0000001.

May I ask a following up question? If I want to amend the condition to be: Add 0.001 to a number which is in the range of 1.234e-6 to 5.678e-5.

Comment: @nam: Just change the condition to `1.234e-6 < $1 && $1 < 5.678e-5`.

Comment: I have tried few combinations to modify the condition but still failed. Is it 'perl -pe 's/ (1.234e-6 < $1 && $1 < 5.678e-5) /$1 == 0 ? $1 : .001 + $1/ge' < input.txt > output.txt'?

Comment: @nam: No, the condition to replace was `$1 == 0`.

Comment: @nam e.g. I have this set of numbers: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f4d748a8327f5c5c6a59

Each number are in between -10 and 10, but the following script fails to add 0.001 to each of them

`perl -pe 's/([0-9.e-]+)/(-10< $1 && $1 < 10) ? $1 : .001 + $1/ge' < input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: @nam: Oh, you have to negate the condition, or switch the "then" and "else".

Comment: May I further know that how to perform the script only for a specific range of lines say from Line 123 to Line 456. I know we can specify in `sed` by '(123,456p)' but I do not know where should I add in `perl -pe 's/([0-9.e-]+)/$1 == 0 ? $1 : .001 + $1/ge' < input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: @nam: It's better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind all non-zero numbers will be in scientific notation form, try:

```
perl -F, -anle '
  for (@F) {$_=sprintf " %e",$_+0.0001 if $_+0}
  print join ",", @F
' file
```

Comment: Thanks cuonglm too. Your solution also works and I appreciate your help too. However, I dare not changing too much about the format of those numbers.